# GPG keeps prompting for the passpharse

Tags: x11, gpg

I've setup my GPG keys by importing them form my keybase.io, then extracted ssh keys and everything seems to work, but one thing I can't figure out is that it prompts me for passphrase every single damn time I need to interact with my git repos.

When I'm using GNOME it stores it in keyring and doesn't bother me with the prompt, but in X11 session it just pops it every time I re-login. How do I make it store it forever?

I don't know if that matters I'm using EXWM as my window manager

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-agent` or `gpg-agent` with the option `--enable-ssh-support` must be running and you have to export the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to those processes which shall use the passphrase caching:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh # example value
```